# How to subconsciously pronounce tones when speaking?

Tags: pronunciation, tones, spoken

When going through my flashcard deck, I can frequently get the tones right for the cards. Equally, when reading a text aloud or slowly speaking, I can generally hit the tones accurately.

However, when speaking at a faster pace without consciously thinking of the correct pronunciation for the character, I often find that I revert to a sort of toneless way of speaking - as in English. I might hit a couple of high-frequency words right, but otherwise pronunciation is abysmal. For example: *今天的旅游真的不错* might be said as *jin4tian1 de5 lu4you4 zhen5 de5 bu4 cuo4*.

Any tips for accurate pronunciation during speech without having to slow down in order to recall the correct tones? I have no opportunities to speak with anyone in my region, but other ways to improve would be much appreciated. I'm nearing the end of the HSK 5 level, but my speaking skills are nowhere near that.

Comment: The answer is almost always more practice. :)

Comment: Processes that are difficult at first, even when focused on consciously, become gradually more automated. There is no magic trick here, practice really is the only way.